# Android databinding data not passed while including custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-databinding

I want to include my custom view with databinding from fragment and pass values to bind. Unfortunately, these values are not passed, getters always return null.

This is my custom view custom_view.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="label"
        type="String" />

</data>

<com.my.package.CustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text='@{label}' />

</com.my.package.CustomView>
```

and its code CustomView.java

```
public class CustomView extends ConstraintLayout {

    CustomViewBinding binding;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        binding = CustomViewBinding.bind(this);
        Log.i("binding", "l:" + binding.getLabel()); // I/binding: l:null
    }
}
```

now this view is included by fragment.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

        <include
            layout="@layout/custom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:label="@{@string/main_menu_some_title}" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/custom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:label='@{"asd"}' />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle =
            new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, string.navigation_drawer_open,
                    string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Both methods (reference and literal value) giving same result. Any clue what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Post your activity code plz.

Comment: Updated as requested